# PHP append variable to url in address bar

Tags: php, variables, url, append

I would like to know if its possible to append a variable to url in address bar when page loads.

demo: http://communityimpact.com/discussions/

Current page is geolocated, if category = Central Austin...would like the url to load as http://communityimpact.com/discussions/central-austin

```
<?php echo $my_category; ?> = Central Austin
<?php echo $my_category_slug; ?> = central-austin
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually headers are your best bet if you need to append variables to url.

Example:

```
$my_category = "Central Austin";
$my_category_grub = "central-austin";


    header("location: community-impact/discussions/$my_category_grub");
//or append a var like this:
header(" location: community-impact/discussions/?location=$my_category_grub");
//then you could handle the request on the new page
```

But both of these methods would redirect you.

If you want to use $_SESSION vars would make more sense. I don't see any possibility of appending vars to URL without redirecting. Url is the address, if you change the Url then you HAVE to change page. But session vars live until they leave your site. And can hold that info hope this helps, I'm not sure what your purpose is.

```
$_SESSION["category"] = "central-austin";
```

But you have to have

```
session_start();
```

at the beginning of the page.

Comment: Need quotes around those 2 variables' values, plus a semi colon :)

Comment: Yeah haha definitely. Sorry for the typos. Fixing.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a redirection with [headers](http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php), like

```
header("Location: http://communityimpact.com/discussions/central-austin");
```

Comment: This doesn't really append the URL - it forces the browser to a different page.

Comment: @HPierce ...which contains the value, therefore it works out well ^^

Answer (score 1):

Your probably should use JavaScript, there are two options here:

- With a redirection

  ```
  // similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
  window.location.replace("http://communityimpact.com/discussions/central-austin");

  // similar behavior as clicking on a link
  window.location.href = "http://communityimpact.com/discussions/central-austin";
  ```
- [Without redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354511/2805783)